# Encode an object to be read by UINibDecoder

Tags: ios, encoding, nib

ViewControllers in a storyboard are activated with initWithCoder and decoder UINibDecoder. How do I encode my objects so that this initWithCoder later finds them. I checked that if I use:

```
   [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self];
```

the encode function is apparently called with a different encoder so that a new call to initWithCoder does not find it and returns nil.

How do I "coalesce" them?